# What's the meaning of require: 'ngModel'?

Tags: angularjs

This is the HTML for my directive:

```
<textarea data-modal="modal" data-mydir ng:model="abc"></textarea>
```

In my directive I have this:

```
return {
  require: 'ngModel',
  replace: true,
  scope: {
    modal: '=modal',
    ngModel: '=',
    pid: '=pid'
  }
}
```

Can someone tell me, what's the significance of require: `ngModel` ?  I see this in many different directives. Could I call this data-modal?

I am confused because when I change it to `data-modal` I get a message from Angular saying

```
Controller 'ngModel', required by directive 'textarea', can't be found!
```

Comment: Wherever you are using this directive there should be an attribute defined as `ng-model='property'`

Comment: Can I have a data-ng-model instead? Also why do I sometimes see: "require: '?ngModel'," It's confusing.

Answer (score 124):

The `require` instruction gives you the controller for the directive you name as the fourth argument to your `link` function. (You can use `^` to look for the controller on a parent element; `?` makes it optional.) So `require: 'ngModel'` gives you the controller for the `ngModel` directive, [which is an `ngModelController`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angModel.NgModelController).

Directive controllers can be written to provide APIs that other directives can use; with `ngModelController`, you get access to special functionality that's built into `ngModel`, including getting and setting the value. Consider the following example:

```html
<input color-picker ng-model="project.color">
```

```javascript
app.directive('colorPicker', function() {
  return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
      element.colorPicker({
        // initialize the color to the color on the scope
        pickerDefault: scope.color,
        // update the ngModel whenever we pick a new color
        onColorChange: function(id, newValue) {
          scope.$apply(function() {
            ngModel.$setViewValue(newValue);
          });
        }
      });

      // update the color picker whenever the value on the scope changes
      ngModel.$render = function() {
        element.val(ngModel.$modelValue);
        element.change();                
      };
    }
  }
});
```

This directive uses the `ngModel` controller to get and set the value of the color from the colorpicker. See this JSFiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/BinaryMuse/AnMhx/

If you're using `require: 'ngModel'`, you probably shouldn't *also* be using `ngModel: '='` in your isolate scope; the `ngModelController` gives you all the access you need to change the value.

The bottom example on [the AngularJS homepage](http://angularjs.org/) also uses this functionality (except using a custom controller, not `ngModel`).

---

As for the casing of a directive, for example, `ngModel` vs `ng-model` vs `data-ng-model`: while Angular supports using multiple forms on the DOM, when you refer to a directive by name (for example, when creating a directive, or using `require`), you always use the lowerCamelCase form of the name.

Comment: Is there a particular reason `require: 'ngModel'` should be used over `ngModel: '='` ?

Comment: Thanks finally a answer that shows how to use ngModel in a way that works with ng-model-options :)

Answer (score 34):

As stated in the [Creating Custom Directives](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) documentation: *(Firstly to your question in the comment)*

> Can I have a `data-ng-model` instead?

The answer:

> **Best Practice**: Prefer using the dash-delimited format (e.g. `ng-bind` for `ngBind`). If you want to use an HTML validating tool, you can instead use the `data`-prefixed version (e.g. `data-ng-bind` for `ngBind`). The other forms shown above are accepted for legacy reasons but we advise you to avoid them.

Examples:

> ```
> <my-dir></my-dir>
> <span my-dir="exp"></span>
> <!-- directive: my-dir exp -->
> <span class="my-dir: exp;"></span>
> ```

Secondly, what does the `?ngModel` represent?

```js
// Always use along with an ng-model
require: '?ngModel',
```

When using your directive, it forces it to be used along with the attribute/controller `ng-model`.

#### The `require` setting

*(Extract from the book* AngularJS *by Brad Green & Shyam Seshadri)*

> Other directives can have this **controller** passed to them with the **require property** syntax. The full form of require looks like:
>
> ```js
> require: '^?directiveName'
> ```
>
> Options:
>
> 1. `directiveName`
>
>    This camel-cased name specifies which directive the controller should come from. So if our `<my-menuitem>` directive needs to find a controller on its parent `<my-menu>`, we’d write it as myMenu.
> 2. `^`
>
>    By default, Angular gets the controller from the named directive on the same element. Adding this optional `^` symbol says to also walk up the DOM tree to find the directive. For the  example, we’d need to add this symbol; the final string would be `^myMenu`.
> 3. `?`
>
>    If the required controller is not found, Angular will throw an exception to tell you about the problem. Adding a `?` symbol to the string says that this controller is optional and that an exception shouldn’t be thrown if not found. Though it sounds unlikely, if we wanted to let `<my-menu-item>`s be used without a `<mymenu>` container, we could add this for a final require string of `?^myMenu`.

Answer (score 22):

The `require:'ngModel'` and `require:'^ngModel'` allow you to inject the model attached to the element or its parent element on which the directive is bound to.

Its basically an easiest way to pass ngModel into the link/compile function instead passing it using a scope option. Once you have access to ngModel, you can change its value using `$setViewValue`, make it dirty/clean using `$formatters`, apply watchers, etc.

Below is a simple example to pass ngModel and change its value after 5 seconds.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/t2GAS/2/

```
myApp.directive('myDirective', function($timeout) {
  return {
    restrict: 'EA',
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
        ngModel.$render = function() {
            $timeout(function() {
                ngModel.$setViewValue('StackOverflow');  
            }, 5000);                
        };
    }
  };
});
```