# AngularJS - Directive ngModel doesn't get updated

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ngmodel

I have a good understanding of AngularJS Directives, but I'm thinking I'm missing something here with my directives.

**What's wrong :** On the initial page load, the ngModel gets triggered correctly and I successfully receive the data and it's modeled in the input.

Everything I do after... doesn't work. If I modify the text in the input, the model is not updated.

Please note that if I don't use a directive (straight HTML), it works fine.

**I have a directive like so :**

```
.directive('defaultFormGroup', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        templateUrl: 'form-group.html',
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            uniqueId: '@',
            labelTitle: '@',
            placeholderText: '@',
            ngModel: '=',
            bsLabelClasses: '@',
            bsFormControlClasses: '@'
        }
    };
})
```

**The directive's template :**

```
<div class="form-group">

    <label class="{{bsLabelClasses}} control-label text-left" for="{{uniqueId}}">{{labelTitle}}</label>

    <div class="{{bsFormControlClasses}}">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="{{uniqueId}}" placeholder="{{placeholderText}}" data-ng-model="ngModel">
    </div>

</div>
```

**And here's how I call the directive in the template:**

```
<div data-default-form-group 
     data-label-title="Name" 
     data-placeholder-text="Name" 
     data-unique-id="name" 
     data-bs-label-classes="col-sm-2 col-md-2" 
     data-bs-form-control-classes="col-sm-3 col-md-3" 
     data-ng-model="site.name">
</div>
```

**I also have the same issue with radio buttons :**

```
.directive('radioSwitch', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        templateUrl: 'radio-switch.html',
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            ngModel: '=',
            radioName: '@',
            firstId: '@',
            firstValue: '@',
            firstLabel: '@',
            secondId: '@',
            secondValue: '@',
            secondLabel: '@',
        }
    };
})
```

**Template:**

```
<input type="radio" name="{{radioName}}" value="{{firstValue}}" id="{{firstId}}" data-ng-model="ngModel">
<label for="{{firstID}}">{{firstLabel}}</label>

<input type="radio" name="{{radioName}}" value="{{secondValue}}" id="{{secondId}}" data-ng-model="ngModel">
<label for="{{secondID}}">{{secondLabel}}</label>
```

**HTML:**

```
<div data-radio-switch 
     data-ng-model="site.existingCustomer" 
     data-first-label="Yes" 
     data-second-label="No" 
     data-radio-name="existingCustomer" 
     data-first-value="True" 
     data-first-id="true" 
     data-second-value="False" 
     data-second-id="false">
</div>
```

What am I missing?

**UPDATE**
I was missing something in my directive... I want to choose the inputType (text, email, password, etc...)

If it's a textarea, the HTML is different... but it seems this line doesn't work `data-ng-if=" inputType !== textarea ">` ... if I remove it, it works

Anyone know why?

Here's a plunker : http://plnkr.co/edit/ITElF2epihSALeTutQAz

Comment: I think you need to require ngModel rather than declare it on scope of your directive

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20930592/whats-the-meaning-of-require-ngmodel

Comment: Instead of scope, you can access these values via attrs inside the link function (you'd need to add one)

Comment: can you post your controller code.

Comment: Can you set up a plunker demonstrating the issue? Here is an angular template: http://plnkr.co/edit/WprgipAdFBtxDKM6jogo?p=info

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be something wrong with the directive itself: look at the example below with your directive, you can see that `model` which is the `ng-model` attribute of the directive gets updated. So, please try to reproduce your problem so we can help you (either embedded snippet, or jsfiddle, or just more code)

```js
angular.module('test', [])

.controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.model = 'foo';
})

.directive('defaultFormGroup', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        template: '<div class="form-group"> <label class="{{bsLabelClasses}} control-label text-left" for="{{uniqueId}}">{{labelTitle}}</label> <div class="{{bsFormControlClasses}}"> <input type="text" class="form-control" id="{{uniqueId}}" placeholder="{{placeholderText}}" data-ng-model="ngModel"> </div> </div>',
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            uniqueId: '@',
            labelTitle: '@',
            placeholderText: '@',
            ngModel: '=',
            bsLabelClasses: '@',
            bsFormControlClasses: '@'
        }
    };
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="test" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <div>model: {{model}}</div>
  <div default-form-group ng-model="model"></div>
</div>
```

Update: it seems that the issue comes from the ng-if, as reproduced in the following snippet. It is fixed by using nh-show instead, as the ng-if may loose the binding from your directive. I am not clear about the exact cause though.

```js
angular.module('test', [])

.controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.model = 'foo';
})

.directive('defaultFormGroup', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        template: '<div ng-if="true"><input type="text" data-ng-model="ngModel" /></div>',
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            ngModel: '='
        }
    };
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="test" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <div>model: {{model}}</div>
  <div default-form-group ng-model="model"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: This does work... but it doesn't use a templateUrl. I tried using this method and it works if I put the template directly in the html, which isn't something I want to do...

Comment: I added a Plunker using a templateUrl, it seems my ng-if doesn't work as intended

Comment: Oh that's better. The problem is your ng-if within your template. Without it it does work. I don't have time to really understand why though, but it's an interesting problem. For now I guess you could use ng-show