# Using an AngularJS directive, how do I pass a custom model from one directive to another?

Tags: angularjs

## Background

I am building a custom form building directive.  Yes, I am aware that there are many out there already, thanks.

Using `ngModel` from within my directive, I loop through a JSON array of control objects for my form:

```
$scope.myForm.controls = [{label: "foo", controlType: "input"}, {label: "bar", controlType: "checkbox"}];
```

From there, the plan is to `$compile` in individual directives for each form control.

Here is the primary directive (working fine):

```
app.directive('myDynamicForm', ['$compile', function ($compile) {
           
    return {
        restrict: 'E', // supports using directive as element only
        scope: {
            ngModel: "="
        },
        replace: true,
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

            angular.forEach(scope.ngModel, function (model) {

                var el = "";

              switch (model.controlType.toLowerCase()) {
              case "input":
                  el = "<my-input ng-model='model'></my-input>";
                  break;
                  default:
                      break;
                }
              
                $compile(el)(scope);
                element.append(el);
            });
      }
    };
}])
```

Here is the usage:

```
<my-dynamic-form ng-model="myForm.controls"></my-dynamic-form>
```

**Again, this part works fine.**

## Problem

As I create those new directive-based elements, I need to pass to them--**as their ng-model**--the specific object being iterated over in the `forEach` loop of the prime directive.

So, here is an example control directive:

```
directive('myInput', ['$compile', function ($compile) {
   return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            ngModel: "="
        },
        replace: true,
        templateUrl: "/templates/input.html",
        link: function (scope, element) {

            var obj = scope.ngModel; //<==SHOULD BE SAME AS "model" IN THE FORM BUILDING DIRECTIVE!!
        }
    };
}])
```

Usage:

```
<myInput ng-model="[model from parent form building directive]"></myInput>
```

Right now, if I set the ng-model of the child directive to `<my-input ng-model='ngModel'></my-input>`, I get the same collection that the parent directive is iterating.

If I set it to "model" `<my-input ng-model='model'></my-input>` I get `undefined` as the value of the child directive.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You should try using 'require' for the ngModel and no isolated scope, see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20930592/whats-the-meaning-of-require-ngmodel) question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try to access child model by index:

```
app.directive('myDynamicForm', ['$compile', function ($compile) {

return {
    restrict: 'E', // supports using directive as element only
    scope: {
        ngModel: "="
    },
    replace: true,
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

        angular.forEach(scope.ngModel, function (model, index) {

            var el = "";

          switch (model.controlType.toLowerCase()) {
          case "input":
              el = "<my-input ng-model='ngModel[" + index + "]'></my-input>";
              break;
              default:
                  break;
            }

            $compile(el)(scope);
            element.append(el);
        });
  }
};
}])
```