# Directive does not watches for value attribute changes

Tags: angularjs

I have a color picker that gets opened when I click in input field and it writes back selected RGBA string to input's `value` attribute.

At first I thought that by adding `ng-model="color"` to the `input` tag will be sufficient for `color` variable to hold/bind rgba string of color that I choose, but it didn't worked. So I have tried to add custom directive to watch for input's `value` attribute changes by

```
// js
.directive('bindInput', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.$watch( attrs.value , function (v) {
                console.log('value changed, new value is: ' + v);
            });
        }
    };
})

// html (jade)
input#text-highlight(ng-model="color",type="text",value="",bind-input)
```

If I open up console I could see that `value changed` gets outputted once on refresh. If I try to change color by opening up color picker I can see that the value appears in input, if I check value's attribute value with jquery (by $("text-highlight").val()) I can also see that the new color value is set to input's `value` attribute. But why I do no get any more `value changed` messages in the console?

Maybe I am doing something completely wrong here. In result what I want to have is just new color value being stored under `$scope.color`.

Comment: This answer on directive + color picker may be useful for you http://stackoverflow.com/a/20930713/3819736 http://jsfiddle.net/BinaryMuse/AnMhx/

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind property of the scope to your directive to watch it inside directive:

```
return {
    restrict: 'AE',
    scope: {
      myVar: '='
    },
   ...
}

  $scope.$watch('myVar', function(value) {
    // do something 
  });
```

And in your case you have to something like this :

```
scope: { value : '@'};

scope.$watch(attrs.value, function (newVal) {
  //do something with the new val
});
```