# Angular ng-required not working with custom directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, required-field, angularjs-forms

I am using Angularjs version 1.5 to validate the inputs in my form.

- ng-required is used to validate the all input required

However, its not working with a custom directive which renders a combo. The combo retrieves the items based on parameter passed to it named 'listId'. Then, it iterates on the 'lookupItems' using ng-repeat. I guess something is missing, like ngModel. Why and how to implement it?

**The combo directive:**

```
app.directive('combo', function($http) {
    return {
        restrict: 'AE',
        template: '<div class="input-group"> <select ng-model="selectedItem">' +
            '<option  ng-repeat="option in lookupItems" value={{option.ListValueID}}>{{option.Translation.Value}}</option></select>' +
            '  {{selectedItem}} </div>',
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            listId: '=',
            defaultItem: '=',
            selectedItem: '='
        },
        controller: function($scope) {
            $http({
                method: 'GET',
                url: '/home/listvalues?listid=' + $scope.listId
            }).then(function(response) {
                $scope.lookupItems = response.data;
            }, function(error) {
                alert(error.data);
            });
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {}
    };
});
```

**The html view:** is iterating over attributes which contains the type of control to render, then its set ng-required to a boolean based on 'attribute.Required' which is true.

```
<form name="profileAttributesForm" ng-controller="metadataCtrl" class="my-form">
    <div ng-repeat="a in attributes">
        <div ng-if="a.DataType == 1">
            <input type="text" name="attribute_{{$index}}" ng-model="a.Value" ng-required="a.Required" />
            <span ng-show="profileAttributesForm['attribute_{{$index}}'].$invalid">Enter a Text</span> text : {{a.Value}}
        </div>

        <div ng-if="a.DataType == 4">
            <div combo list-id="a.LookUpList" name="attribute_{{$index}}" selected-item="a.Value" ng-required="a.Required"></div>
            <span ng-show="profileAttributesForm['attribute_{{$index}}'].$invalid">lookup Required</span> Value from lookup: {{a.Value}}
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

**Sample of attributes ($scope.attributes) which is iterated over in the form,** I am providing it just for illustration purposes:

```
[{
    "AttributeID": 1,
    "DataType": 4,
    "NodeID": 0,
    "Name": "Name",
    "Description": null,
    "LookUpList": 1,
    "SortAscending": false,
    "Required": true,
    "DefaultValue": "1",
    "Order": 1,
    "Value": ""
}, {
    "AttributeID": 3,
    "DataType": 1,
    "NodeID": 0,
    "Name": "Job Title",
    "Description": null,
    "LookUpList": 0,
    "SortAscending": false,
    "Required": true,
    "DefaultValue": null,
    "Order": 2,
    "Value": ""
}, {
    "AttributeID": 4,
    "DataType": 1,
    "NodeID": 0,
    "Name": "Email",
    "Description": null,
    "LookUpList": 0,
    "SortAscending": false,
    "Required": true,
    "DefaultValue": null,
    "Order": 3,
    "Value": ""
}]
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In order for [ngRequired](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRequired) to set its validator **it requires [ngModel](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel) to be set on the same element in order to get [NgModelController](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController) from it**, otherwise it will just set the required attribute on or off without affecting the parent form.

A forms state ($pristine, $valid, etc) isn't determined by its HTML **but by the registered NgModelControllers**. A controller is added automatically when an ngModel is linked inside of the form.

- For example, this `<input required type="text">` won't affect the form's validity, even if it's required, since it doesn't have ngModel assigned to it.
- But this `<div ng-model="myDiv" required></div>` will affect it since it's required and has ngModel assigned to it.

In your case, I see two solutions:

- **the simple one:** move ngRequired inside `combo` and add it on the same element as ngModel; for this you'll also need to add a new scope variable, e.g. `isRequired`
- **the complex one:** add `require: 'ngModel'` to your directive and make the appropriate changes in order for this to work. **This way you'll have greater control and flexibility**. For example, what will you do if, down the road, you want to add [ngModelOptions](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModelOptions) to `combo`? If you don't implement this solution, you'll have to add it manually.

  You can start by reading [What's the meaning of require: 'ngModel'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20930592/whats-the-meaning-of-require-ngmodel) - it's an awesome question/answer which contains different examples. For a more in-depth explanation, have a look at [Using NgModelController with Custom Directives](https://www.nadeau.tv/using-ngmodelcontroller-with-custom-directives/). As a side note, in Angular 1.5 they improved the syntax of `require` - see [$onInit and new "require" Object syntax in Angular components](https://toddmotto.com/on-init-require-object-syntax-angular-component/).

Comment: Thanks @Cosmin. Can you provide a link or example for the complex solution, that elaborates how to implement it?

Comment: @h.salman Sure! I've edited my answer and added a bunch of articles which may help you.