# TypeError: Cannot set property '$render' of null

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I got a **TypeError: Cannot set property '$render' of null** because I didn't set the model in some of the components.
So, how could I do this:

```
.directive("contenteditable", function () {
        return {
            restrict: "A",
            require: "?ngModel",
```

and create a `<div contenteditable class="title-module-name" required></div>` without a ng-model?
Maybe I need to check before:

```
ngModel.$render = function () {
   element.html(ngModel.$viewValue || "");
};
```

but I don't know how to do this!

Thank you!

My entire directive:

```
.directive("contenteditable", function () {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        require: "?ngModel",
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {

            function read() {
                ngModel.$setViewValue(element.text());
            }

            ngModel.$render = function () {
                element.html(ngModel.$viewValue || "");
            };

            element.bind("blur keyup change", function () {
                scope.$apply(read);
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Similar question: [Cannot set property '$render' of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37936946/cannot-set-property-render-of-undefined)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I ended up with this:**

```
link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
    if (ngModel !== null) { //the check
```

so, self answered! Thanks!