# Accessing ng-model in html from the controller in the component

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This is my template html

```
<form name="myForm">
    <label for="name"><span>Name*: </span>
        <br>
        <input 
               name="myName" 
               type="name" 
               id="name" 
               minlength="3" 
               maxlength="16" 
               autofocus="on" 
               required 
               placeholder="   Ajay" 
               ng-model="$ctrl.myName" 
               autocomplete="name">
    </label>
</form>
```

Component Code:

```
angular.module('loginPage')
 .component('loginPage',{
    templateUrl: 'login/login.template.html',
    controller: ["$scope",function control($scope,params){

    }]
});
```

I want to access the ng-model in the template inside the controller (function control()). How can I do that?

Comment: You can access the model from a directive or component using the `require` part of the directive object and using functions of the required controller in the `link` function.  See this answer to [What's the meaning of require: 'ngModel'?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20930713/691711).  You won't really do this in the `controller` part of the component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HTML:**

```
<form name="myForm">
    <label for="name"><span>Name*: </span>
        <br>
        <input name="myName" type="name" id="name" minlength="3" maxlength="16" autofocus="on" required placeholder="Type any name" ng-model="name" autocomplete="name">
    </label>
</form>
```

**JS:**

```
angular.module('loginPage')
    .component('loginPage', {
        templateUrl: 'login/login.template.html',
        controller: ["$scope", function control($scope) {
            console.log($scope.name);
        }]
    });
```

Comment: I do not want to edit the input. Rather I want to obtain the value from the input in real time. How do I do that?

Comment: edited. The ng-model **name** for your input will bind data to $scope of the attached controller. You can obtains data through scope

Comment: quick pointer to Data binding in AngularJS http://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_databinding.asp

Answer (score 0):

It can be achieved by using 
    bindings: {
      name: '<'
    }

in component definition object. Such that name will be available in the controller.

In the template ng-model="$ctrl.name" instead of ng-model='name'