# angularjs directive - capitalize

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have this code below working fine when a user is typing an input data. But my problem is when the data is from the `database(auto filled)` my directive is not working(capitalize the letter
). Is there a reason why its not working?.

But when using a `class="text-uppercase"` its working.

**HTML**

```
<input ng-model="profile.Name" type="text" placeholder="" maxlength="40" capitalize />
```

**JS**

```
app.directive('capitalize', function ($parse) {
return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function (scope, element, attrs, modelCtrl) {
        var capitalize = function (inputValue) {
            if (inputValue === undefined) { inputValue = ''; }
            var capitalized = inputValue.toUpperCase();
            //for (var i = 0; i < capitalized.length; i++) {
            //    capitalized[i] = capitalized[i].charAt(0).toUpperCase() + capitalized[i].substring(1);
            //}
            if (capitalized !== inputValue) {
                modelCtrl.$setViewValue(capitalized);
                modelCtrl.$render();
            }
            return capitalized;
        }
        modelCtrl.$parsers.push(capitalize);
        capitalize($parse(attrs.ngModel)(scope)); // capitalize initial value
    }
  };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check below for more information on **require: 'ngModel'** configure setting.

[What's the meaning of require: 'ngModel'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20930592/whats-the-meaning-of-require-ngmodel)